# JsonValidator - Missing Error Line (Newtonsoft Json)

Tags: c#, json, error-handling, json.net

I am using a custom JsonValdiators to validate a json file. This is the class:

```
public class IntValueValidator : JsonValidator
{
    public override bool CanValidate(JSchema schema)
    {
        return schema.Format == "intValue";
    }

    public override void Validate(JToken value, JsonValidatorContext context)
    {
        if (value.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            var inputString = (int)value;
            if (inputString > 15)
            {
                context.RaiseError($"Int value too high, should be < 16 was {inputString}");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want to raise an error saying which line in the file the error occured in. Currently the LineNumber property in the list of errors passed to the .IsValid() function:

```
json.IsValid(_schema, out listOfErr)
```

Is always empty.

Schema:

```
_schema = generator.Generate(typeof(MyClass));
        var settings = new JSchemaReaderSettings
        {
            Validators = new List<JsonValidator> { new IntValueValidator() }
        };
        _schema = JSchema.Parse(_schema.ToString(), settings);
```

Any ideas how can I access a line number inside of the Validate function?